# Sliding UI Like following mentioned Images

Tags: android

As per my project requirement I want to implement Sliding UI as shown in Images below in my activity.
[image]

[image]

[image]

As Shown in images below we can slide by dragging down arrow image.I want to implement same feature in  my activity. How to do that? Any idea? or any references?
Please help I am working on it from 15 days but didn't got any success.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html).

Comment: Sliding drawer is of no use since it can not stop in between.
It will either fully open or fully close.